# sql полнотекстный поиск выдает ошибку

Tags: php, sql

При выполнении запроса на полнотекстный поиск выдает ошибку Unknown column 'search' in 'where clause', сам запрос :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `sandoz` 
WHERE MATCH (AssetType, AssetSubtype, UniqID, Asset_Status, SN, CR_IMEI) 
      AGAINST (". $_POST["search"] .")
```

не могу найти решение проблемы

Comment: `var_dump($sql);` после этой строчки и сюда результат.

Comment: в конструкции AGAINST текст поиска надо брать в скобки, ответ дал ниже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sandoz` WHERE MATCH (AssetType, AssetSubtype, UniqID, Asset_Status, SN, CR_IMEI) AGAINST ('". $_POST["search"] ."')";
```

Comment: я поправил, ниже уже написал ответ))

Answer (score -1):

при поиске задал неиндексируемые столбцы в таблице без ключей по-этому и не ищет, добавил индексы ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX ('Asset') и ALTER TABLE table name ENABLE KEYS вписал